# OpenCV: VideoCapture::get(CV_CAP_PROP_FPS) returns 0 FPS direct video input without using camera in java

Tags: java, opencv, netbeans

```
 VideoWriter videoWriter = new VideoWriter(outputFile, fourCC.toInt(), videoCapture.get(Videoio.CAP_PROP_FPS),
                    frameSize, true);
```

this return framesize as 0

Comment: please help .i try to motion detecction in video ,for that use github code but  out put is

Comment: In your code what is ` frameSize, true);`

Comment: final Size frameSize = new Size((int) videoCapture.get(Videoio.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH),
    (int) videoCapture.get(Videoio.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT));
  logger.log(Level.INFO, String.format("Resolution: %s", frameSize));

Comment: final Size frameSize = new Size((int) videoCapture.get(Videoio.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH),
    (int) videoCapture.get(Videoio.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT));
  logger.log(Level.INFO, String.format("Resolution: %s", frameSize)); i try to find using this video framesize but get 0

Comment: Did you open the video before doing this?

Comment: VideoCapture videoCapture = new VideoCapture(url);

Comment: https://github.com/sgjava/install-opencv this link from this i try to run project but not work

Comment: please go through this link and guide me where i wrong

Comment: i use windows ,opencv 3.0.1

Comment: or if you have any other solution to motion tracking from video in java please suggest me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution** At first you try to open the video and check if opened successfully as below:

```
VideoCapture capture = new VideoCapture(filePath);
if(!capture.isOpened()) {
    System.out.println("Cannot open the video.");
    return;
}
```

If it not returned, then it opened successfully, now you read the frame and display or at least check the height and width of the frame as below:

```
Mat frame = new Frame();
capture.read(frame);
int width = (int) capture.get(Videoio.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH);
int height = (int) capture.get(Videoio.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT);
System.out.println("width = " + width );
System.out.println("height = " + height);
```

If everything goes well then, it is OK, you can use `capture` and read the frames, if not working, go to your `OpenCV` extracted folder and copy this line

```
C:\opencv\build\x64\vc14\bin
```

to your `Environment Variable` and restart the your PC and try again.

Comment: I try this but video is not open ,also set path in environment variable

Comment: i use 32 bit system so i set C:\opencv\build\x64\vc12\bin

Comment: You set the path according to your system, if it is 32 then use the correct one, if you don't set this correctly, in OpenCV 3, the video may not open.

Comment: i use  open cv 3.1.0 because opencv 3.0 not contain videowriter class

Comment: I know what you say, when I say OpenCV 3 it means 3.0 or 3.1 or 3.x etc, OpenCV 3.0 has some bug and shortness like it doesn't have video writer... which is solved in 3.1 version, but for reading video regardless it is 3.0 or 3.1 all needs to set the Environment Variable, Otherwise it not possible to open video stream form video file.

Comment: Thanks a lot ...video is open

Comment: video is open but when try to detect motion from video it show file size is zero

Comment: I don't know how did you do it, you maybe pass an empty Mat to the OpenCV function.

Comment: Resolution: 480x360
926 frames, 737 frames with motion  69.9 FPS, elapsed time: 13.24 seconds i got this result but motionPercent = 100.0 * Core.countNonZero(gray) / totalPixels; that value is always 0

Comment: My E-mail: bahram_120@hotmail.com

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105421/discussion-between-kanchan-and-bahramdun-adil).

Comment: When i give input of 10min video it take to detect motion almost 10 min ,i want reduce this time